# How to display tags order by asc or desc when post add and edit in wp-admin

Tags: wordpress, wp-admin, post-meta

I want to display Tags (Post Meta) order by in post add and post edit.
Also I want to display Tags in drop down list.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in your php file

```
$tags = get_tags( 'order=ASC&orderby=slug' );
```